# Can I specify half-open scale ranges in rule-based QGIS layer styles?

Tags: qgis, symbology, style, scale, rule-based

In QGIS 2.16.1's rule-based symbology as well as in its rule-based labeling, it's possible to enable a "scale range" to which the visibility of the result of the respective rule (be it a symbology style or a label style) shall be limited. However, it seems that these ranges always require both a minimum **and** a maximum scale.

What can I do if I want a rule to apply to all scales above a certain scale (i.e. more "zoomed in"), but not below (more "zoomed out")? The logical way would seem to be to leave out the maximum or set it to `1 : +∞` or at least to something ridiculously large like `1000000 : 1` (= `1 : 0.000001`), but the QGIS UI seems to allow none of these and resets the value to the last one entered that is ≤ `1 : 1`.

(And no, `1 : 1` is not the largest (most "zoomed in") scale that might occur in QGIS as you can easily verify by zooming further in on your map.)

So, is there a way to specify only a minimum scale and have a rule apply to all scales above it?

Comment: Is this something that has changed? From http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/42437/51574 I take half-open scale ranges (open in either direction) were possible back in 2012 when that question was asked.

Comment: The behaviour in that question ^ doesn't work for me, it won't allow me to delete the initial scale, simply setting it back to what it was before.  That's working in version 2.14.3.

Comment: Eh, I guess it's simply a UI bug then. I'll try to report it.

Comment: bug filed as https://hub.qgis.org/issues/15512

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the minimum value to 1:0 seems to allow you to zoom further than 1:1.  I've successfully taken a dataset down to 1000:1.

It does seem to be a little bit unstable and resets itself if you tamper with the minimum scale, so set that first and then set the maximum scale.

EDIT - in fact it appears to set the GUI scale displayed back to 1:1000 every time you open the layer options but the rule still appears to work.

[image: It appears to display correctly in the rule overview]

[image: It doesn't appear correctly when you open the dialogue]

Comment: That's what I observe, too, except that the value snaps back as soon as the input field loses focus, so I can't ever get it to contain no value.